# The website with id x that was requested wasn't found

Tags: magento2

I was trying to access my store today but this showed up, I couldn't find any working solutions.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): The website with id 2 that was requested wasn't found. Verify the website and try again.
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): The website with id 2 that was requested wasn't found. Verify the website and try again.<pre>#1 Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager->getWebsite(2) called at [generated/code/Magento/Store/Model/StoreManagerInterface/Proxy.php:135]
#2 Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface\Proxy->getWebsite(2) called at [vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Resolver/Website.php:31]
#3 Magento\Store\Model\Resolver\Website->getScope(2) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ScopeCodeResolver.php:49]
#4 Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeCodeResolver->resolve('websites', 2) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php:69]
#5 Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('getresponse/web-...', 'websites', 2) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#6 Magento\Framework\App\Config\Interceptor->___callParent('getValue', array('getresponse/web-...', 'websites', 2)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#7 Magento\Framework\App\Config\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('getresponse/web-...', 'websites', 2) called at [app/code/WeltPixel/Quickview/Plugin/ScopeConfig.php:38]
#8 WeltPixel\Quickview\Plugin\ScopeConfig->aroundGetValue(&Magento\Framework\App\Config\Interceptor#000000002c740ec7000000001994ffe5#, &Closure#000000002c740b25000000001994ffe5#, 'getresponse/web-...', 'websites', 2) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#9 Magento\Framework\App\Config\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('getresponse/web-...', 'websites', 2) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#10 Magento\Framework\App\Config\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getValue', array('getresponse/web-...', 'websites', 2), NULL) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Config/Interceptor.php:26]
#11 Magento\Framework\App\Config\Interceptor->getValue('getresponse/web-...', 'websites', 2) called at [vendor/getresponse/magento2/Domain/Magento/Repository.php:118]
#12 GetResponse\GetResponseIntegration\Domain\Magento\Repository->getWebEventTracking(2) called at [vendor/getresponse/magento2/Block/Header.php:41]
#13 GetResponse\GetResponseIntegration\Block\Header->getTrackingCodeSnippet() called at [vendor/getresponse/magento2/Block/Header.php:30]
#14 GetResponse\GetResponseIntegration\Block\Header->getTrackingData() called at [vendor/getresponse/magento2/view/frontend/templates/header.phtml:8]
#15 include('/var/www/html/ve...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&GetResponse\GetResponseIntegration\Block\Header#000000002c7406a2000000001994ffe5#, '/var/www/html/ve...', array('csp' => &Magento\Csp\Helper\InlineUtil#000000002c740833000000001994ffe5#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callParent('render', array(&GetResponse\GetResponseIntegration\Block\Header#000000002c7406a2000000001994ffe5#, '/var/www/html/ve...', array('csp' => &Magento\Csp\Helper\InlineUtil#000000002c740833000000001994ffe5#))) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&GetResponse\GetResponseIntegration\Block\Header#000000002c7406a2000000001994ffe5#, '/var/www/html/ve...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callPlugins('render', array(&GetResponse\GetResponseIntegration\Block\Header#000000002c7406a2000000001994ffe5#, '/var/www/html/ve...', array()), array(array('csp_helper_plugi...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php/Interceptor.php:26]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->render(&GetResponse\GetResponseIntegration\Block\Header#000000002c7406a2000000001994ffe5#, '/var/www/html/ve...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:271]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/html/ve...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:301]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1100]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1104]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:674]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:566]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('getresponse.trac...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:542]
#27 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('getresponse.trac...') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#28 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('getresponse.trac...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:497]
#29 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('getresponse.trac...', true) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#30 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('getresponse.trac...', true) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:525]
#31 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml() called at [vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/container.phtml:7]
#32 include('/var/www/html/ve...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]
#33 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template#000000002c74092a000000001994ffe5#, '/var/www/html/ve...', array('csp' => &Magento\Csp\Helper\InlineUtil#000000002c740833000000001994ffe5#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#34 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callParent('render', array(&Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template#000000002c74092a000000001994ffe5#, '/var/www/html/ve...', array('csp' => &Magento\Csp\Helper\InlineUtil#000000002c740833000000001994ffe5#))) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#35 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template#000000002c74092a000000001994ffe5#, '/var/www/html/ve...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#36 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callPlugins('render', array(&Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template#000000002c74092a000000001994ffe5#, '/var/www/html/ve...', array()), array(array('csp_helper_plugi...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php/Interceptor.php:26]
#37 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->render(&Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template#000000002c74092a000000001994ffe5#, '/var/www/html/ve...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:271]
#38 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/html/ve...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:301]
#39 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1100]
#40 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1104]
#41 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:674]
#42 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php:251]
#43 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000002c740ea7000000001994ffe5#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php:171]
#44 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000002c740ea7000000001994ffe5#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#45 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000002c740ea7000000001994ffe5#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#46 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000002c740ea7000000001994ffe5#) called at [app/code/Magefan/RocketJavaScript/Model/Controller/ResultPlugin.php:74]
#47 Magefan\RocketJavaScript\Model\Controller\ResultPlugin->aroundRenderResult(&Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor#000000002c740af2000000001994ffe5#, &Closure#000000002c740fed000000001994ffe5#, &Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000002c740ea7000000001994ffe5#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#48 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000002c740ea7000000001994ffe5#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#49 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000002c740ea7000000001994ffe5#), NULL) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:130]
#50 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000002c740ea7000000001994ffe5#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:120]
#51 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#52 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#53 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000002c740ebc000000001994ffe5#) called at [index.php:40]</pre>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at your error message, the line

```
GetResponse\GetResponseIntegration\Domain\Magento\Repository->getWebEventTracking(2) called at [vendor/getresponse/magento2/Block/Header.php
```

tells us the website 2 should be in your database. I suggest you take a look whether you have a website with an id 2 (this will be in your database and the table will be store_website)

Once you know if you have a website with an id 2 or not, then the next step will be to find where in your code there is something using the website id 2 in a hard-coded fashion.

I imagine the website id 2 may be hard-coded, I'd take a look first in the files:

module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/container.phtml --> line 7
getresponse/magento2/view/frontend/templates/header.phtml --> line 8

if these 3 files don't give results, my method is quite simple: just follow the error message and open the files that are mentioned and scan these specifically paying attention at the line you see in the error message

Comment: You sir saved my life, the problem was that the Get Response module caused some error with the current Magento version I have, I already disabled all modules before to diagnose but I didn't care about this one since it's just an email one. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like  your store website ID has been changes for some reason. If you have a access to the admin panel then navigate to the Stores => All Stores. And check the website code Or ID

Comment: Thank you for your response, the ID is all correct, I checked in the database and everything is set as it should be, all common solutions failed for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this query in your database.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: That's the first solution I tried, as I mentionned I tried all common solutions, thank you by the way.